# javascript function disabling and/or conflicting with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being a bit of a javascript/jQuery noob, I've run into a problem that I can't find a solution for.

I have a function that grabs some parameters from the url and replaces elements.  All good.  I also have instances of FancyBox on the page.

It semms something in my getUrlVars function is killing FancyBox.  If I load FancyBox first in the document ready, it just loads the larger pic into a new browser window, like a regular link.  If I grab the URL vars and let them do their thing before loading FancyBox, the links do nothing at all.

I've tried running both in isolation and they work perfectly, until I try to run them both.

Here's the getUrlVars script...

```
function getUrlVars()
{

var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}

 var salesname = getUrlVars()["agent"];
 var salesname = unescape(salesname);
 var vendor = getUrlVars()["vendor"];
 var vendor = unescape(vendor); 
 var position = getUrlVars()["position"];
 var position = unescape(position);

$('h1:contains("thisiswherethevendorgoes")').html( '<span class = "fade-in one">    <strong>Prepared for ' +  vendor + '</strong></span>');

$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/salesname/g, salesname + ', ' + position));

});
```

Before or after (I've tried every permutation) I setup FancyBox...

```
$("a#fbs").fancybox({
            'opacity'       : true,
            'overlayShow'   : true,
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'easingIn'      : 'easeInCirc',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            'easingOut'     : 'easeOutCirc',
            'speedIn'       : 500,
            'speedOut'      : 250

        });
```

Both have to run (I think?) inside $(document).ready(function() {

Any clues?  Any and all suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error in javascript console of chrome or Firebug when you're running both ?

Comment: Nope.  Wish I was, then I'd have some clues!

Comment: Well, you are replacing the whole body's content. Maybe this hurts (but i don't know in which way). Couldn't you think of another way to achieve this replacing ? Could you post some html for us to get the full picture ?

Comment: That's it, thanks Didier.  Rookie mistake. Commented out that line and it works, now I'll just figure a less lazy way to do it.  You should put it in an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are replacing the whole body's content. I guess this is a bit hurtful.

This plugin [jQuery replaceText](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/spotlight-jquery-replacetext/) replaces all occurrences of a a string in the textNodes only, which won't require you to reapply all the body.

```
$('<body>').replaceText(/salesname/g, salesname + ', ' + position);
```

Note: This solution will not work if you need to replace text in html attributes though.

Nevertheless, you might maybe search for a less consuming task like replacing everything from the body element.
Do you use any server-side processing, like asp.net, or such ?

d.

Comment: That's the one Didier, thank you!  I've replaced that line with the same as the one above it (different tags of course) and it's all as it should be.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below syntax to avoid the conflict

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Except there is no other library.  Just vanilla javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood noConflict if for use if you're trying to use mootools or something as well.  Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an exact answer, but have done a full source compare between what your markup looks like between the three different scenarios?

Scenario A:  getUrlVars (present)
Scenario B:  fancybox (present)
Scenario C:  both (present)

I know that I have had numerous issues with using fancybox and a lot of them have been due to the way that the page rendered and how I was attempting to tie fancybox to a specific object that rendered differently in the page than expected.  Reviewing source/markup has generally helped me in these types of situations.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but as a test I did a page with one image, linking to another larger one and the scripts to keep it as simple and plain as possible.  No joy sadly, and nothing in there to confuse things.